# Can't run a command using Raspi_Runner

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, script

I've setup Raspi_Runner to auto run commands reading from a text file every x minutes. Raspi Runner is a BASH script which runs all your scripts delivered by e-mail. It works good with commands like this one `sudo wakeonlan 57:87:66:30:22` and this one `sudo poweroff`. Now I've setup ssmtp to send emails from command line. If I write this command by myself in command line `sudo echo "test" | ssmtp sample@gmail.com` and then hit enter, email arrives immediately to my address. But when I use Raspi_Runner and reads this command from .txt file, it can't run the command. Anyone knows why? It drives me crazy. Thanks.

Comment: What is Raspi_Runner?

Comment: Raspi Runner is a BASH script which runs all your scripts delivered by e-mail.

Comment: Do you send every x minutes an email? How does get the scripts from the email into a text file?